# Crash of application using CameraX : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, firebase, crash, android-camerax

I'm building an application that recognize basic emotions on user's face.
For this app, I'm using CameraX and Firebase.

When I want to launch an activity that uses CameraX, the app is crashing, and I have the following error :

```
     --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.camerax, PID: 16061
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkArgument(Unknown Source:41)
        at com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImageMetadata$Builder.setRotation(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage.fromMediaImage(Unknown Source:24)
        at com.example.camerax.RealtimeActivity$2.analyze(RealtimeActivity.java:163)
        at androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis$2.onImageAvailable(ImageAnalysis.java:291)
        at androidx.camera.core.AndroidImageReaderProxy$1.onImageAvailable(AndroidImageReaderProxy.java:105)
        at android.media.ImageReader$ListenerHandler.handleMessage(ImageReader.java:812)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16061 SIG: 9
```

Here is my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.camerax"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    //RAJOUT
    def camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
    //implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.0-alpha06'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //RAJOUT
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2'
}
```

Thanks for your help, I searched all the night on forums, but I don't found any solution.
Noucho

Comment: Have you tried using the beta version of CameraX?

Comment: @Noucho Could you post your source code, you might not have given proper value of rotation.